# php eamil not sending the data

Tags: php, html, email

hey there I have a small problem when I send my email I only revive the `<br>` as you see and from the `<form>` its not sending anything. Thank you in advance 
This is my php

```css
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])){
$companyname = $_POST['Company Name:'];
$companynumber = $_POST['Company Number:'];
$ypozition = $_POST['Your Pozition:'];
$f_name = $_POST['First Name:'];
$l_name = $_POST['Last Name:'];
$m_name  = $_POST['Middle Name:'];
$mail = $_POST['Email Address:'];
$phone = $_POST['Phone Number:'];
$postcode = $_POST['Post Code:'];
$snumber = $_POST['Street Number:'];
$sname = $_POST['Street Name:'];
$advert = $_POST['Advert From:'];
$comm = $_POST['Comments:'];

$to      = 'rlafrem@gmail.com';
$from  = '$companyname';
$subject = '$f_name';

$message = "<br>$companyname<br><br>$companynumber<br><br>$ypozition<br><br>$f_name<br>".$m_name."<br><br>".$l_name."<br><br>".$mail."<br><br>"
.$phone."<br><br>".$postcode."<br><br>".$snumber." <br><br>".$sname."<br><br>".$advert."<br><br>".$comm."<br><br>";

mail($to, $subject, $message);
echo ("<p>An email have been sent</p>");
echo ("<p>Thank you</p>");
}else ("we appologise our email form its unaviable unknown error");
?>
```

```html
This its my html 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>I Need Work</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Jumbotron Header -->
        <header class="jumbotron hero-spacer">
            <h1>Register your company</h1>
            <p>Once you are done you will be contacted whitin 24h</p>
        </header>
        <hr>
        <!-- Title -->
        <!-- /.row -->
        <!-- Page Features -->
        <div class="row text-center">
<div class="row text-center">
<div class="caption">
<form name="CompanyRegister" method="post" action="mpost.php">
<table width="800" align="center"
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="companyname">Company Name</label></td>
 <td valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="companyname" maxlength="50" size="30" />
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td width="197" valign="top">
<label for="companynumber">Company Number</label>
 </td>
 <td width="591" valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="companynumber" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td width="197" valign="top">
<label for="ypozition">Your Pozition</label>
 </td>
 <td width="591" valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="ypozition" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td width="197" valign="top">
<label for="f_name">First name</label>
 </td>
 <td width="591" valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="f_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
<label for="m_name">Middle name</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="m_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
<label for="l_name">Last name</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="l_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="mail">Email</label>
  </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="mail" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="phone">phone</label>
  </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="phone" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
<label for="postcode">Post Code</label>
</td>
 <td valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="postcode" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
<label for="snumber">Number</label>
</td>
 <td valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="snumber" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
 <tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="sname">Street name</label></td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="sname" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
  <tr>
                
      </tr>
      
 <td valign="top">
 
  <label for="advert">How did you find us ?</label>
  </td>
  <td valign="top">
<select name="advert">

<option value="none">none</option>
<option value="adgoogle">google</option>
<option value="ademail">mail from us</option>
<option value="adfriend">from a friend</option>
<option value="adpaper">paper advert</option>
</select>
</td>
<tr>
</tr>
 

 <td valign="top">
 
  <label for="comm">Comments</label>
 
 </td>
 
 <td valign="top">
 
  <textarea  name="comm" cols="50" rows="8">Anything you wood like to know or say ?</textarea>
 
 </td>
 
</tr>

<tr>
<td valign="top">
 
  <label for="submit"></label>
 
 </td>

<td valign="top">
 
  <input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Become a member" maxlength="30" size="30">
 
 </td>
 
</tr>
</table>
</form>
         </div>
         </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->


        <hr>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <p>Copyright &copy; Your Website 2015</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="login.php" class="btn btn-primary">Members area </a>
            <p></p>
            <a href="newmembers.html" class="btn btn-primary">Become a member </a>
            <p></p>
            <a href="aviable.html" class="btn btn-primary">Agencys aviablile </a>
            <p></p>
            <a href="aboutus.html" class="btn btn-primary">About us</a>
        </footer>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- jQuery -->

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited for more suggestions below.

This line:

```
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

will only happen if 'submit' is NOT set in the posted variables.

You need to remove the exclamation point so that everything will work the way you are expecting.

Also note that the code inside the else part of your statement will not show on the screen the way it is written.

You could try:

```
echo "this is the error message you want to show on the screen";
```

or

```
die("this is the error message you want to show on the screen");
```

EDIT:
Also, where you set the $message variable you have several errors.

```
$message = "<br>$companyname<br><br>$companynumber<br><br>$ypozition<br><br>$f_name<br>".$m_name."<br><br>".$l_name."<br><br>".$mail."<br><br>".$phone."<br><br>".$postcode."<br><br>".$snumber." <br><br>".$sname."<br><br>".$advert."<br><br>".$comm."<br><br>";
```

should be:

```
$message = "<br>".$companyname."<br><br>."$companynumber."<br><br>".$ypozition."<br><br>".$f_name."<br>".$m_name."<br><br>".$l_name."<br><br>".$mail."<br><br>".$phone."<br><br>".$postcode."<br><br>".$snumber." <br><br>".$sname."<br><br>".$advert."<br><br>".$comm."<br><br>";
```

Comment: steal no i am only reeving the <br> from $message , no variables that are to be in between the <br> its sent out

Comment: as HenryTK mentioned, are you making sure that the identifier in $_POST matches the name of the input in your HTML?  In your example about, where it says $companyname = $_POST['Company Name:'];  it should say $companyname = $_POST['companyname']

Comment: also, your code is missing some important punctuation.  See the line where you set the variable $message.  You are missing many quotation marks and periods if you want to add the actual contents of your variables.

Answer (score 1):

The string passed as an identifier in `$_POST` must match the `name` attribute in the HTML exactly.

For example:

`<input  type="text" name="companyname" maxlength="50" size="30" />`

Would be accessed via:

`$_POST['companyname']`

Also, the line `if (!isset($_POST['submit']));` isn't doing anything, because you are not defining a block in curly braces `{}` after it.

Example:

```
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // Do something
}else{
    // Do something else
}
```

Comment: Could you update the question with your code exactly how it is now?

Comment: MR Hanry its steal not sending the data Checking its possible in my live host http://transylvanyanorthampton.com/wfuk/compreg.html